# can I use .txt files in JAVA using VS code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, text-files

[image]

I am trying to access the text file in java and the code I have works in other IDEs but in VS code it keeps saying `File Not Found` - (produced from my exception handling)

I can't find anything about how to access text files with VScode. Is this possible please and does anyone know how?

I have tried to create the file in VScode with the `new text file` option and also by loading a pre-existing file and get the same result each time

Comment: The question is where the files is actually located relative to the java file, the jar, the project, etc.

Comment: It's not VSCode or the .txt extension that's causing the problem. When you start the java vm your program opens a file, the vm looks for that file in the process's working directory. The file obviously is not there. How do you start your program?

Comment: Don’t post pictures of your source code. Insert the relevant part as text. That’s actually easier than making a screenshot.

Comment: Either use absolute addressing, like `C:\Data\Integers.txt`, or put the File in the directory where the VM is running the java/jar file. Hint: use `System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));` in your code, it will tell you the execution location.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `.txt` file in the project root directory so that the code reads to the file location. As shown below

[image]

If the file is not with the project, use absolute paths in the code.

[image]